# how to remove an array item from firestore using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add a delete button to my page. the event listener callback is working properly except for the updateDoc function.

```
const deleteBook = document.getElementsByClassName('deleteBook');
for (let i = 0; i < deleteBook.length; i++) {
    deleteBook[i].addEventListener('click', async () => {
        //book to delete
        const bookToDelete = deleteBook[i].parentElement.firstElementChild.textContent
        // collection title to delete the book from 
        const bookCol = deleteBook[i].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.firstElementChild.textContent
        // get a snap of the database
        const docRef = doc(dataBase, 'users', `${auth.currentUser.uid}`)
        const docSnap = (await getDoc(docRef)).data();
        // loop over the collections and get a match with the bookCol
        for (const col in docSnap) {
            if (docSnap[col].title === bookCol) {
                console.log('col to delete from found')
                console.log(`book to delete ${bookToDelete}`)
                await updateDoc(doc(dataBase, 'users', `${auth.currentUser.uid}`), {
                    [`${col}.books`]: arrayRemove(`${bookToDelete}`)
                }).then(()=>{
                    // fullfiled
                    console.log('book deleted')
                }, ()=>{
                    // rejected
                    console.log('promis rejected')
                })    
            }
        } 
    })
}
```

Col is the object that contains the books array. In the console it always prints book deleted, but in the firestore console, nothing changes. this is a screenshot of the database.[image]

I would really appreciate any help and thank you.

Comment: Can you run `console.log(col, bookToDelete, auth.currentUser.uid)` before updateDoc function and share the output?

Comment: You will need to edit the question to show your debugging information.  We can't see the values of any of the variables you're using here, nor do we know that you're actually modifying the document that you show here.  Your question should contain enough information that anyone can use the reproduce the behavior your observe.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @dharmaraj I did that and they are all evaluated correctly each time but their value is dynamic depending on user input. the code should work for all cases.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have modified the document several times in this project using the same code with arrayUnion and it worked. but now that I'm using arrayRemove, it doesn't have any effect on the database.

Comment: The problem is that we can't see any of that to know for sure what's going on.  Please read through the link I shared about creating a complete minimal example.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo Done. if there is another way to get the target collection to delete from, please tell me, because comparing the titles is the only way I know to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated the behavior that you're experiencing. I tried changing the content of `${bookToDelete}` to any word or even ID. It always returns `book deleted` even if its deleted or not. The line of code below should be changed in order to get the correct output.

```
.then(()=>{
   // fullfiled
   console.log('book deleted')
}, ()=>{
   // rejected
   console.log('promis rejected')
})
```

I have created a workaround for your use-case with this kind of issue. See snippet below:

```
const db = getFirestore();

const colName = "users";
const arrayName = "books";
const usersCol = collection(db, colName);
const userRef = doc(db, colName, `${auth.currentUser.uid}`);
const arrayRef = `${col}.${arrayName}`;
const q = query(usersCol, where(arrayRef, "array-contains", `${bookToDelete}`));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
.then((querySnapshot) => {
    // Removal of object will not proceed if the querySnapshot is empty.
    if ((querySnapshot.empty)) {
        console.log("No object found!");
    }
    else {
        // Proceeds to removal of object.
        updateDoc(userRef, {
            [arrayRef]: arrayRemove(`${bookToDelete}`)
        })
        .then(() => {
            // Check again if the object was deleted successfully.
            const querySnapshot = getDocs(q)
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
                if ((querySnapshot.empty)) {
                    console.log("Book Deleted!");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Failed!");
                }
            })
        });
    }
})
// Catch if there are any Firebase errors.
.catch(error => console.log('Failed!', error));
```

The workaround that I created will query the object in the array then remove the object in the array if it exist. After removing, it will query again to check if the object has been deleted and logs `Book Deleted!`. Vise versa for checking if the object doesn't exist on the 1st query, it will not proceed on removing them and logs  `No object found!`.

***The workaround itself can still be improved. You can add any logic you want for your use-case.***

---

**I'd also recommend to create a [Feature Request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) if you want to have this kind of feature together with the `arrayRemove` Method.**